# interpreting the remote filepath from a FTP request

Tags: shell, powershell, ftp, cmd

I have the following FTP request that is saved as a CMD script. It works. I want to write an FTP request in PowerShell that does the same thing. In order for the PowerShell script to work, I need to specify the address of the remote file I want to get.

Here is the CMD script. From looking at this, can you tell what the file path is? FYI in case this is important: this is being pulled from an AS400.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set uname=USERNAME
    set passw=USERPASS
    set hostname=AS400NAME
    set filespec=SPECNAME
echo %uname%>                     TEST.ftp
echo %passw%>>                    TEST.ftp
echo cd DIRECTORYNAME>>           TEST.ftp
echo binary>>                     TEST.ftp
echo get %filespec%>>             TEST.ftp
echo bye>>                        TEST.ftp
ftp -s:TEST.ftp %hostname%
if errorlevel 1 pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to reassemble the key variables from that script to build the new string in PowerShell. I believe you have the required pieces in the provided script:

```
$uname = "USERNAME"
$passw = "USERPASS"
$hostname = "AS400NAME"
$filespec = "SPECNAME"
$dir = "DIRECTORYNAME"
```

You just need to piece those together to build a valid FTP URI:

```
$uri = "ftp://$uname`:$passw@$hostname/$dir/$filespec"
```

In PowerShell, strings that are wrapped in double quotes will internally expand variables. It makes for a much cleaner string as compared to successive concatenations.

The last step would be to retrieve the file. I would recommend using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($uri, "C:\temp\$filespec")
```

Comment: +1, this looks good. i am having trouble resolving the ftp address. i will accept this answer once that is done, and i see that this solution works.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I accepted your answer because it answers my question about interpreting the FTP request. If you are so inclined, please take a look at a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983593/translate-cmd-ftp-request-to-powershell-ftp-request).