# translate CMD FTP request to PowerShell FTP request

Tags: shell, powershell, ftp, cmd, etl

I have a fully-working FTP request saved to a .CMD file.

Here is my CMD script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set uname=exUsername
    set passw=exPassword
    set hostname=exHostname
    set filespec=exSpec
echo %uname%>                     test.ftp
echo %passw%>>                    test.ftp
echo pwd>>                        test.ftp
echo cd exDir>>                   test.ftp
echo binary>>                     test.ftp
echo get %filespec%>>             test.ftp
echo bye>>                        test.ftp
ftp -s:test.ftp %hostname%
if errorlevel 1 pause
endlocal
```

I want to translate the above code to a PowerShell script.

Here is my PowerShell script:

```
$uname = "exUsername"
$passw = "exPassword"
$hostname = "exHostname"
$filespec = "exSpec"
$dir = "exDir"

$uri = "ftp://$uname`:$passw@$hostname/$dir/$filespec"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($uri, "C:\")
```

My PowerShell script so far does not work. Here is my error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception
>   occurred during a We bClient request." At line:20 char:17
>   + $wc.DownloadFile <<<< ($uri, "C:\")
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I initially thought that I am specifying the wrong FTP address, so I entered the `$uri` value into Windows explorer and got onto the server, but noticed that there were no (visible) folders available to access.

However, the exact same `$uri` filepath is getting me the requested file thru the CMD script.

Any ideas about where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT** - at the request of @KeithHill , I reworked the script to use `ftpWebRequest` instead of `WebClient`. Code is below, but I am getting the following error:

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote
>   server returned an error: (431) 431 Requ ested security mechanism not
>   available at this time. ." At line:23 char:39
>   + $ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   The term 'Write-Out' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program . Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
>   .

Code below:

```
$uname = "exUsername"
$passw = "exPassword"
$hostname = "exHostname"
$filespec = "exSpec"
$dir = "exDir"

$uri = "exUri"


# Create an FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the FTP server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri)

# Set the request's network credentials for an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($uname,$passw)

# Set FTPWebRequest method to ListDirectory
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory
$ftprequest.EnableSsl = $True
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $True
$ftprequest.UsePassive = $True
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $False

$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()

Write-Out $ftpresponse.StatusCode
Write-Out $ftpresponse.StatusDescription
```

Comment: Have you tried to use powershell cmd lets? For example http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/09/ftp-transfers-automation.html

Answer (score 1):

For `DownloadFile`, the second parameter must be a filename like `"c:\$filespec"` and not just a drive specifier.

Comment: I changed it to `$wc.DownloadFile($uri, "C:\$filespec")` but I am getting the same error as in my post.

Comment: Right after you run that command and you get the error, execute `$error[0] | fl * -force` to see if you can get some additional details on the exception.

Comment: BTW you might try using FtpWebRequest instead of WebClient for this.

Comment: additional details: `System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.` I will look into FtpWebRequest, but if you can tell me if you see any glaring errors with the `$uri` string, please let me know.

Comment: please see edit for my code using `FtpWebRequest`. I am getting an error with that too. I commented out the `Write-Out` lines, and got the following error (present in edit, too) `Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (431) 431 Requ
ested security mechanism not available at this time.`

Comment: Does the FTP server require a client cert to authenticate?  Have a look at this: http://www.enterprisedt.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=7496

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't have access to the IIS logs on my terminal. I'm trying to set up extended logging at the `All` level (per the suggestion on that forum) but so far I'm unsuccessful in setting it up.